# Why contains(Object) is log(n) in TreeMap but O(n) in PriorityQueue, while PriorityQueue uses binary tree (binary heap) internally?

Tags: java, tree, complexity-theory, priority-queue

Why contains(Object) is log(n) in TreeMap but O(n) in PriorityQueue, while PriorityQueue uses binary heap (special kind of a binary tree) internally?  They both use a tree, but PriorityQueue's contains is O(n).

Comment: Not all binary trees are binary *search* trees.

Comment: Where did you read that `PriorityQueue` uses a heap internally?  I could find this nowhere.  `O(n)` search performance is what I would expect from a queue.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen: First line of the [docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/PriorityQueue.html): "An unbounded priority queue based on a priority heap."

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not all binary trees support O(log(N)) searches. Balanced binary *search* trees support that, but the tree underlying a PriorityQueue is a binary heap, not a binary search tree. With a binary search tree, you can tell which subtree to search in at each step. With a binary heap, the heap invariant isn't enough to determine where to look for an element.